# only first xAxisCategory showed. Lots of elements

Tags: highcharts

I am using a highcharts Heat map (I guess its the same with another choice) and I have got 185 elements inside.

To be able to show some usefull xAxisCategories I set the first one to the value, then I set 10 to empty (""). What happends its that when the ones that I show are bigger than one or two characters, it only shows the first one.

Example:

```
xAxisCategory = ["a", "", "" ..... , "" , "a",...]
```

That works and shows the "a" when it has to.

```
 xAxisCategory = ["aaaa", "", "" ..... , "" , "aaaa",...]
```

This only shows the first "aaaa", after that, everything its empty.

What I have to show its a date so it doesnt work.

Comment: Adding a JFiddle to showcase your problem might help in identifying the problem, for yourself and those viewing.

Comment: I would like to, but with 185 elements Jfiddle crashed. Anyway I think its an easy explanation :)

Comment: What do you mean JFiddle crashed? If it does, and that is what you experience, that sounds good to me. The explanation sounds so easy that it doesn't quite add up to being a problem, which is my problem in evaluating it.

Comment: Attach more code. I would suggest to set `xAxis.tickInterval: 1`.